# Powershell script does not run via Windows Scheduled Tasks

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-task-scheduler

I have a VB application which generates a PDF file then runs a powershell script which prints it.

If I run the application manually (by double-clicking on it or through the DOS screen) everything works.  The pdf gets generated & printed.

If I run the application through windows scheduled tasks the pdf gets generated but it doesn't get printed!

This is my powershell script:

```
Start-Process –FilePath $DocumentName –Verb PrintTo $PrinterName -PassThru | %{sleep 20;$_} | kill
```

at run time it becomes something like this:

```
Start-Process –FilePath E:\MyFolder\mydocument.pdf –Verb PrintTo MyPrinter -PassThru | %{sleep 30;$_} | kill
```

I tried changing it to this:

```
Start-Process –FilePath "E:\MyFolder\mydocument.pdf" –Verb PrintTo MyPrinter -PassThru | %{sleep 30;$_} | kill
```

but that hasn't worked either.

If paste it in powershell command line, it works fine!

Any suggestion anyone?
Thanks

System: Windows Server 2012 R2
This is my VB code for executing the powershell script:

```
        Dim MyRunSpace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()
        MyRunSpace.Open()
        Dim MyPipeline As Pipeline = MyRunSpace.CreatePipeline()
        MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText)
```

Comment: Is this printer a mapped printer or locally installed? Is the task set for "whether a user is logged on" or not? Also you are missing some of the code for your script. How are `$PrinterName` and `$DocumentName` populated?

Comment: It's a mapped printer.  
Yes, the "Run whether is logged on or not" option is ticked.

This is how I replace the document & printer values:
FileContent.Replace("$DocumentName", FileName).Replace("$PrinterName", PrinterName).ToString

Thanks